# Is this a Diff and Diff kind of problem?

Tags: difference-in-difference, recurrent-events

I have a sample of 500 firms and I need to study if an observed variable $y_i$ is different before and after a firm-specific event (happens 4 times in a year).

I have 6 years of data for each firm. Hence, my sample is 4 events x 500 firms x 6 years.

These events can happen any time in the year for any firm but no more than once per quarter.

The problem is different than conventional diff and diff as there is no aggregate level that a treatment (or event) is applicable to. But I thought I could do the following for $t$ being time stamp (each quarter) and $i$ being individual.

$y_{it} = b_{t} + a_{i} + \gamma \times Dummy_{it} + \beta\times x_{it}$

- $x_{it}$ are covariates like firm size, etc
- $b_t$ is the year dummy or fixed time effect.
- Also I would include some market conditions that are same for all 
  individuals as fixed time effect
- $a_{i}$ (don't have any)

The only issue is that there is no fixed control group. But I could create one as:
- for each $i$ and $t$,  I find the firms that have no event in the certain time window of the firm $i$ and $t$. However this would mean for each firm $i$ for each quarter I will have a different control group. I feel that is an overkill.  Please suggest.

Alternatively, I could just use the above mentioned regression as is without any control variables but only use the sample of firms that have events at any time. Then use a time fixed effect such as market conditions to account for the market conditions. And look for significance of dummy coefficient.

$y_{it} = b_t + a_i + \gamma \times Dummy_{it} + \beta \times x_{it}$